# How to write html to a file in android

Tags: java, android, file, android-asynctask, fileoutputstream

I know this has been asked a few times here, but I'm not sure which way I should go.  This code downloads the html file okay, but I get an IOException when trying to write the html to a file.  I've tried many suggestions on sof, but none seem to work for me and I'm at a loss as it seems it should be working.

```
class Downloader extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Void> {
    String site = getResources().getString(R.string.sched_hd_url);
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/directory/");
    File file = new File(dir, "file.html");

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(site);
            URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(site).openStream());
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            int total = 0;
            int count;
            byte data1[] = new byte[1024];
            while ((count = in.read(data1)) != -1) {
                out.write(data1);
                total += count;
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        finish();
    }
}
```

I run this code and no file appears in the directory that I specified.  The directory already exists, and I do have the permissions in my manifest.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will also need an `out.close()` in the `finally` clause too!

Comment: Here's an easy check: is the phone by any chance mounted (i.e., being used) by the computer that's connected to it?  (I know this sounds like a silly check, but this has tripped me up before).  I.e., if your external storage directory is mounted and accessible from your PC, most likely your PC has locked out your app (and your phone for that matter) from accessing the external storage.  (NOTE: this is really a wild guess, I could be way off..)

Comment: How are you checking for the file? If you have a more recent phone where the external storage is emulated, you'll need to invoke the media scanner before the MTP connection (at least) can see your new file.

Comment: I'm using the boolean    `isExternalStorageWriteable();` but I tried this using internal storage too and I'm still not getting it to work.  I tried using the     `out.close()` inside a     `finally` clause but I still get that IOException.      `out.flush()` didn't seem to fix the problem either.

Comment: Well apparently it was the URL I was using.  You have to specify the exactly html file you're downloading.  Links like http:///www.google.com/ won't write anything to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem was a couple of things.  First, I want to thank those that commented.  In my question, I did neglect to put in the `out.close();` method.  When that didn't work, I was looking at the string which held the URL I wanted to use.  That had errors in it.  This fixed the download problem, but I wanted to download from a place where the .html file was not in the URL (example: http://www.example.com/ instead of http://www.example.com/index.html).  It worked for the latter but not the former.  So instead of using `URLConnection` I used `HttpURLConnection`.  Here is my working code:

```
class Downloader extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Void> {
    String site = getResources().getString(R.string.sched_hd_url);
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/directory/");
    File file = new File(dir, "file.html");

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(URL... uri) {
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        if (file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.delete();
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            URL url = new URL(site);
            HttpURLConnection yc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                    new URL(site).openStream());
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            int total = 0;
            int count;
            byte data1[] = new byte[1024];
            while ((count = in.read(data1)) != -1) {
                out.write(data1);
                total += count;
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Also another error in my question was in regards to no implementation checking to see if the file had already existed.  Thanks again for the help.